# untiy3d shadow quality changes in editor but stay the same after build for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine, lighting

I tried changing the shadow quality from the Edit - project settings - quality window. All i wan to do is use hard-shadows instead of processor heavy soft shadows. I even change the settings in each light objects. In the editor it shows block y hard shadows, but when built it is always soft shadows.

Comment: Set your desired quality level using [QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel.html).

Comment: check the [TierSettings](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.TierSettings.html) and the [GraphicsSettings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GraphicsSettings.html)